# How can I "translate" roles picked up in a servlet Preauthentication Filter to Roles that Spring Security can work with?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

Spring Security can be a nightmare for the new user.  Nothing is solid, everything can be configured by some `@Autowired` bean or other, there are a million options, and seemingly simple things become very complex very quickly.

<End of Rant>

Now then, I have the following requirements and setup for a corporate intranet application:

1) I am trying to avoid the use of security.xml and configure everything with java annotations.

2) There is a central corporate cookie-based authentication service which authenticates the user as someone entitled to use the corporate intranet. Usernames and Passwords are handled there, the application does not concern itself with them. There is a wealth of other information there, most of which my application doesn't need.  The one absolute essential there is the userid entered by the user and validated by the service.  This goes into the Principal and also is available as session data.  This service is supplied as a servlet filter.

3) This filter includes a configuration option through which an adaptor can be attached, to perform other tasks, such as getting the authenticated user's application-specific roles from an application-maintained database.  I am using such an adaptor for this task, which adds the roles from the database to an object that winds up in the Session attributes in some structure. By the end of this filter's and adaptor's execution the user's application-specific roles are in the session data.

4) I have added a class derived from `com.att.voicetone.cwing.security.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` and in its `beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain()` method, have registered this filter from step 2 (which includes the adaptor from step 3) so that it is done first.  All the above is working as I want it to work.

5) Now, I am looking at how all this may be tied into Spring Security.  My goal is to be able to use something like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/index.html","/transcripts.html").hasRole("MY_APP_USER");
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/assign.html","/report.html").hasRole("MY_APP_ADMIN");
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/x/**", "/audio/**").hasRole("MY_APP_USER");
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oam/**").hasRole("MY_APP_ADMIN");

}
```

It seems as though what I must do is implement a class that extends `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`, and insert it into the filter chain and somehow code it to translate the role information into a format that the `hasRole()` calls above will find the information they are looking for.

But this is the point, after all the "hard" work has seemingly been done, where I run into countless ConfigurationBuilders, AuthenticationManagers, AuthenticationTokens, etc., all of which have many customization opportunities, none of which seem to fit with the "simple" task I feel is waiting for me, somewhere, in the morass of configurable options, that I haven't been able to find through hours of starting at code, javadocs, etc.

If you've followed me thus far, what is the sweet spot I am missing for translating the roles from the above session object so that SpringSecurity can handle them with the `hasRole()` code?

Or to put it another way, where is `hasRole()` looking and what does it expect to find there?

Comment: Which version of SS? You may need to prefix role authorities with ROLE_

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that you do the "translation" in a AuthenticationDetailsSource, which creates the UserDetails object which has the collection of GrantedAuthorities.  That is the piece that I was missing.

However, I'm still not out of the woods.  On to my next SO question ...